# RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01

Tags: java, android, security

**When do decrypting on Android I got the error :**

`javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:0407006A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:block type is not 01`

**My code are as follows :**

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mRSAPublicKey);
final byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

Any help will be grateful !